# Y es close and complete

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $Y=\{(x_n)\in \mathbb{K}^\infty /: \exists n \in \mathbb{N}  \text{such that} x_n=0 \forall n>N \}$ be. show taht $Y$ is vectorial subspace of $\mathbb{K}^\infty_\infty $, but is not close in $l^\infty(\mathbb{K})$. $(Y,||.||_\infty)$ is not complete.

Solution
Let $(\alpha x_n),(y_n) \in Y$ whit $\alpha x_n=o$ and $y_n=0$ then $x_n + y_n =0$.
Now $Y$ is close i.e. Let $((x_k)^{(n)})_{k>1} \subset Y$ such that $((x_k)^{(n)})_{k>1} \rightarrow (l_k)$ then  show $(l_k)\in Y$

help me please in $(l_k)\in Y$, how show this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sequence $(x^n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of elements of $Y$ defined by
$$x^n_p=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{p} &\text{if} \ p \le n\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$ to prove that $Y$ is not close and not complete. The sequence above is Cauchy, converges in $\ell^\infty$, but not in $Y$.

Comment: Thanks,  but if $l_k \in y $, how show this ?

Comment: The limit exists in $\ell^\infty$ and is unique. And the limit is not eventually vanishing. So it cannot belong to $Y$.

Comment: Why limit exist in  $\ell^\infty ?  $you can explain me? Please.

Comment: $x_p^n$ is constant for $n \ge p$.

Comment: $ Y $ isnt close. How show this without example?

Comment: Try the absurd method, but I could not conclude. Can you suggest some method?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking... I already gave a proof that $Y$ is not close!

Comment: I wanted to formally demonstrate it with definitions, is it possible?